# PHP Delete products / ID

Tags: php, button

So i have this:

```
    echo "
        <form action='users/delete.php' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value='".$row->ProductID."' />
          <input type='submit' value='Delete' />
        </form>
    ";
```

This comes under every item on the webshop: 
[image: Webshop]

That works, but whenever i press the button the table is not being deleted, this is my delete.php

```
<?php

define('_HOST_NAME_', 'localhost');
define('_USER_NAME_', 'root');
define('_DB_PASSWORD', '#####');
define('_DATABASE_NAME_', 'ws_webshop');

//PDO Database Connection
try {
 $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
 $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


    // create PDO instance; assign it to $db variable
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `tbl_products` WHERE `ProductID` = :ProductID LIMIT 1";
    $smt = $databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
    $smt->bindParam(':ProductID', $_POST['ProductID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $smt->execute();

header('Location: ../webshop.php');
```

But it doesnt remove it, does anyone see the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: try by taking out limit 1 from the query.

Comment: What happens if you put the query in the `try`? Is `$row->ProductID` populated as well, maybe that's an array?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\new\3n\webshop.php on line 120
LINE 120
           <input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value='".$row->ProductID."' />

Comment: Fixed it, changed value to : value='".$row['ProductID'] Thanks guys

Comment: *Another happy ending*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$row` usage is for an object, but you have an array. So either change your fetch to:

```
->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

-http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

or change your usage to:

```
echo "
        <form action='users/delete.php' method='post'>
          <input type='hidden' name='ProductID' value='".$row['ProductID'] . "' />
          <input type='submit' value='Delete' />
        </form>
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

`$sql = "DELETE FROM 'tbl_products' WHERE 'ProductID' = :ProductID LIMIT 1";`

try to change to:

`$sql = "DELETE FROM 'tbl_products' WHERE 'ProductID' = ProductID LIMIT 1";`

without the "`:`" close to `ProductID LIMIT 1`.
Try it in the MySQL console.